# Django - refine search results via a searchform with prefilled values

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

On my homepage I have a simple search form. The user can enter some filters and in a next step the search results are diplayed on a new page => this all works:

Below a simplified version of the view.py:

```
def search(request):
    form = SearchForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SearchForm(request.POST)
        results = search(form)
        return render_to_response('search_results.html',{'results': results},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = SearchForm()
    return render_to_response('search.html',{'form': form},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Now the problem:
In a next step I want to add the same searchform in the `search_result.html` page. The purpose would be that the user can refine the search results using that search form. In an ideal world the search form on `search_results.html` has already the filters entered in `search.html` prefilled.

I'm struggling a bit on how to approach this. Should I pass the orginal entered filters as a list to the `search_result.html` page? How can I do this? And how can I put these values as a default in the form? Maybe I'm overthinking this somehow, but at this moment I don't see a good solution.

Any feedback, directions are very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just make your context dict `{'results': results, 'form': form}`?  This would make the form available again with the previously posted data already bound to the form.

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks for the answer. You are completely right. a simple and clean solution (Propably I was sitting already to long behind the computer to think with a clear mind). Thanks! Kind Regards.